# Automate add an image to another image, and export

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, photo-editing, automation, photoshop-scripting

[image]

I have a white bg image size 500 x 312 - 72 resolution.

[image]

I have about 20 icons that I downloaded from google images. 
They have different size.

Right now, this is what I have to do for one image

- create a frame image with size 500 × 312 with 72 resolution.
- add a layer, add white bg color
- add an image - scale that image to 75% - horizonal/vertical center that image
- export to desktop
- close the window
- repeat for all the images to folders

**Goal**

Rather than keep doing again and again. I'm wondering if there an automated way to do this.

How do I create a photoshop action to do that in batch?

Comment: It seems you could batch process the images using Actions (Macros). Here's a video that talks about [how actions are made](https://youtu.be/rL0LGUAe4Nw). Here's a video showing [one way to batch process images](https://youtu.be/EyRPJW4c1fk). The other way to batch process images you can find in `File > Automate > Batch`.  And [here's some more info](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html). — Then again, if this is really all you need, ImageMagick might even be a simpler way to do it in some regards... (No need to learn a complex GUI)

Comment: It's been 2 days since you asked. so let me know if you still want to do this stuff if yes then i can provide a script for you :)

Comment: Did you check the first two links I posted? You having trouble making the action? (Cause I saw that image you posted and it looked like you made the action just fine) Or are you having trouble with the batch processing? I'm not sure it could be made much clearer than those two videos.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the procedure to (forget about the bg image):

- Make an action with the steps below and Batch to the icons files folder

---

- Open one of the icons
- Open the Actions Panel and click the New Action Icon at the bottom
- Put a name to the action and start to do the steps below
- Menu File → Automate → Fit Image

[image]

- Menu Image → Canvas Size → width 500 + Canvas Extension Color = white

[image]

- Menu File → Save or Export for web and devices as png
- Click the Stop Action Icon at the Actions Panel bottom

---

Once the action is done, go to menu File → Automate  → Batch and play this action to the icons folder

Comment: Do the action with an **open image** and then use this action to batch all the images in the folder

Comment: Answer updated with some details. Remember this is not a tutorial request site ;-)